# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20,475.00"

Tags: java, numberformatter

i am trying to get the running balance of my system. To do it, i get the sum of all numbers in the jtable from column AMOUNT and subtract the sum to the value inside the txtLoanAmount.
 here's my code snippet:

```
String LoanAmount = txtLoanAmount.getText();
float f = Float.valueOf(LoanAmount.trim()).floatValue();
float balance = 0; 
float sum = 0;

for(int i=0;i<=tableLedger.getRowCount()-1;i++) {
    sum = sum + Float.parseFloat(tableLedger.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
}
balance = f - sum;
System.out.println(balance);
```

now i get the error message :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20,475.00"
```

How can i solve this ? any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Float.parseFloat() and Float.valueOf() always will assume that the number is in your local format, here's a short example how to do localized parsing if your locale does not match the number format you're getting.

```
String str = "20,475.00";
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); // Looks like a US format
float f = nf.parse(str).floatValue();
```

Comment: in this, shall i retain all other parts of the code i showed above?

Comment: @zairahCS Instead of using parseFloat and valueOf, use nf.parse(), once you have it parsed as a float, the rest of your code should not need to change.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class instead of `Float.parseFloat`. It will allow you to specify a format for parsing a formatted number such as `20,475.00`.

Example:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
// provided your Locale information matches your number format
sum += nf.parse(tableLedger.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
```

Comment: do i have to change my datytyoe for sum=0 and the other variables above? coz i still get an error

Comment: @zairahCS: of course. you need to adapt the code snippet I put to your code. It's just an example on parsing a formatted number. You will probably have to put that code inside your loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your number is locale-dependent. Normaly a number can only contain optional minus sign at the beginning and optional decimal dot. Comma-separated thousands are not supported.

NumberFormat class, as Pablo Santa Cruz suggested, allows you to specify your own format of numbers and parse according to that format.

If you are going to use decimals, I can suggest using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this two line to convert string into double

> ```
> NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance()
> dounum=nf.parse("24,000.50").toDouble()
> ```